# How do I implement systemjs in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, angular6, systemjs

I'm trying to learn how to make plugins work in Angular, however after adding systemjs I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SystemJS is not defined

I implemented systemjs like this:

```
import { System } from 'systemjs';
declare const SystemJS: System;

import * as angularCore from '@angular/core';
import * as angularCommon from '@angular/common';
import * as angularCommonHttp from '@angular/common/http';
import * as angularForms from '@angular/forms';
import * as angularAnimations from '@angular/animations';
import * as angularPlatformBrowser from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as angularPlatformBrowserDynamic from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

//error thrown here
SystemJS.set('@angular/core', SystemJS.newModule(angularCore));
SystemJS.set('@angular/common', SystemJS.newModule(angularCommon));
SystemJS.set('@angular/common/http', SystemJS.newModule(angularCommonHttp));
SystemJS.set('@angular/forms', SystemJS.newModule(angularForms));
SystemJS.set('@angular/animations', SystemJS.newModule(angularAnimations));
SystemJS.set('@angular/platform-browser', SystemJS.newModule(angularPlatformBrowser));
SystemJS.set('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic', SystemJS.newModule(angularPlatformBrowserDynamic));

SystemJS.config({ meta: { '*': { authorization: true } } });
```

What am I missing?

My code where I use systemjs: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/angular-pluggable-architecture/blob/master/dashboard/src/app/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts

My commit with attempted fixes: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/pluggable-angular-example/commit/4472560da17b69c13809be931f6966d9254d10d1

The repo I use as example: https://github.com/paucls/angular-pluggable-architecture

Comment: Try importing systemjs in your `/src/polyfill.ts` file. We use to import SystemJS in previous versions of Angular but latest version have systemJs in some angular modules.

Comment: @AbdulSamiHaroon I tried to add to polyfill like this `import 'systemjs';` and `import '../node_modules/systemjs';`, but I get the following error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'systemjs' in [...]". What else should I do to add it to polyfill?

Comment: // Add global to window, assigning the value of window itself.
`(window as any).global = window; `

I added this in one of my projects to resolve this error. I have no idea but please try adding it at the bottom of your polyfill.ts.

Comment: @AbdulSamiHaroon I think I did it wrong, it's still not working. Can you look at it? https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/pluggable-angular-example/commit/7d22f37c210d6084b2da47c20cf35da94e9f5b68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install SystemJS through your `package.json` (maybe you need to install an older version for your needs).
2. Add the path to the SystemJS Javascript File to your scripts inside `angular.json`. That way it is loaded into the global space:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"
]
```

3. Declare and use it inside your file.

```
...
declare const SystemJS: System;
...
SystemJS.set('@angular/core', SystemJS.newModule(angularCore));
```

Step 2 is what you are missing (I guess) and also why it works in the repo you linked; it is done the same way: https://github.com/paucls/angular-pluggable-architecture/blob/master/dashboard/.angular-cli.json

What your code is doing is not actually importing the SystemJS module itself, it's only importing the type declaration, which is stripped out at runtime. That's why you need to add SystemJS to the `scripts`-section

Comment: I did add the second step, it turned out I needed version 0.21.5, in this commit it works: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/pluggable-angular-example/commit/9c4515c2f5d5da14291d2c7df3b9db509a8d7ae8

Comment: Looks like "newModule" was deprecated and removed from systemjs.  Any idea what the replacement is in the newest release?